# In-App Purchase; AppStore returns invalid identifier

Tags: ios7, xcode5, storekit

AppStore always returns a response 'invalid identifier'.

I wrote following code, and give product identifier as argument, productId.

```
- (void)purchase:(NSString *)productId callbackURL:(NSString *)callbackURL {
    if (![SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        DDLogWarn(@"couldn't make purchase");
        return;
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    NSSet *productIds = [NSSet setWithObject:productId];
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIds];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    if (!response) {
        DDLogError(@"Product Response is nil");
        return;
    }

    [response.invalidProductIdentifiers bk_each:^(id obj) {
        DDLogWarn(@"%@ is a invalid identifier", obj);
    }];

    [response.products bk_each:^(id obj) {
        SKProduct *product = obj;
        DDLogDebug(@"%@ is a valid product", product.localizedTitle);
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }];
}
```

However, always receive a response, invalid identifier.

I saw http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ , and check my code, device and iTC and provisioning profiles.

My application's state is waiting for upload, inapp items are yellow signals.
Registered application bundle identifier and Xcode project's are same string.

Why..!? Thanks.